# add + to facet result

Tags: solr, solrj, facet, faceted-search

i need to add + to facet results. Like this:

```
"facet_counts": {
  "facet_queries": {},
  "facet_fields": {
    "color": [
      "red", +74,
      "white", +53
...
```

Is there a way to do this using solr queries or solrj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so this possible at solr end.
But you need to achieve the same thing at client side.

When you get json response you modify the same by adding the '+'.

Or

You where your displaying the facet count on the UI front you just need to add the '+' as prefix before showing the count.